# XSLT: Create node if it doesn't exist?

Tags: xslt

How can I use XSLT to create nodes if they don't exist?  I need to insert the node <sectionhead> under <group>, but if the <group> node doesn't exist, then I need to create that as well.

eg.

Input (group node exists):

```
<story>
    <group>
        <overhead>
            <l1>overhead</l1>
        </overhead>
        <headline>
            <l1>headline</l1>
        </headline>
    </group>
    <text>
        <lines>
            <l1>line</l1>
        </lines>
    </text>
</story>
```

Output:

```
<story>
    <group>
        <sectionhead />
        <overhead>
            <l1>overhead</l1>
        </overhead>
        <headline>
            <l1>headline</l1>
        </headline>
    </group>
    <text>
        <lines>
            <l1>line</l1>
        </lines>
    </text>
</story>
```

Input (group node does not exist):

```
<story>
    <text>
        <lines>
            <l1>line</l1>
        </lines>
    </text>
</story>
```

Output:

```
<story>
    <group>
        <sectionhead />
    </group>    
    <text>
        <lines>
                <l1>line</l1>
            </lines>
    </text>
</story>
```

Comment: Lots of different variations of <xsl:if test="not(group)"><xsl:copy><group><sectionhead   /></group></xsl:copy><xsl:copy-of select="@*|*"/>...

Comment: `<xsl:if test="not(group)">` is the way to go. You are just testing it on the wrong context node, I suspect.

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete, short and easy solution, using the most fundamental and powerful XSLT design pattern -- overriding the identity rule.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try to translate the rules in your problem description directly into template rules:

"I need to insert the node `<sectionhead>` under `<group>`"

```
<xsl:template match="group">
  <group>
    <sectionhead/>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </group>
</xsl:template>
```

"but if the `<group>` node doesn't exist, then I need to create that as well."

```
<xsl:template match="story[not(group)]">
  <story>
    <group>
      <sectionhead/>
    </group>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </story>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 10):

**Here is a complete solution that overrides the identity rule/template for any `story` element that has no `group` child:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="story[not(group)]">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
     <group>
       <sectionhead />
     </group>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="group[not(sectionhead)]">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
     <sectionhead />
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when it is applied on the provided XML document (with no `group`):**

```
<story>
    <text>
        <lines>
            <l1>line</l1>
        </lines>
    </text>
</story>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
<story>
   <group>
      <sectionhead/>
   </group>
   <text>
      <lines>
         <l1>line</l1>
      </lines>
   </text>
</story>
```

**when applied to the first XML document (having `group` that has no `sectionhead` child):**

```
<story>
    <group>
        <overhead>
            <l1>overhead</l1>
        </overhead>
        <headline>
            <l1>headline</l1>
        </headline>
    </group>
    <text>
        <lines>
            <l1>line</l1>
        </lines>
    </text>
</story>
```

**this same transformation again produces the wanted, correct result:**

```
<story>
   <group>
      <sectionhead/>
      <overhead>
         <l1>overhead</l1>
      </overhead>
      <headline>
         <l1>headline</l1>
      </headline>
   </group>
   <text>
      <lines>
         <l1>line</l1>
      </lines>
   </text>
</story>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:for-each select="//story/group">    
  <sectionhead />  
  <xsl:copy-of select="." />  
</xsl:for-each>  
<xsl:for-each select="//story/text">  
  <group><sectionhead /></group>
  <xsl:copy-of select="." />  
</xsl:for-each>
```

Two phase - ok ?

Comment: This is flawed on several levels.