# XSLT: create node if does not exists

Tags: xslt, xml-parsing

I know similar questions are already there but none of them seem to work for me.

So shortly, I have XML file with tag "Lokal" that in most cases does not appear but it should. Not making things easier: I also need to change a name of "Lokal" to let's say "Lokal_test". My goal is modify node name(if exists) or create it and rename (if does not exists).
Data from XML will be imported to MS Access data so they need to match perfectly with table...

Sample XML:

```html
<Dane>
  <InformacjeOWpisie>
    <DaneAdresowe>
      <AdresGlownegoMiejscaWykonywaniaDzialalnosci>
        <Budynek>3a</Budynek>
        <Wojewodztwo>podlaskie</Wojewodztwo>
      </AdresGlownegoMiejscaWykonywaniaDzialalnosci>
    </DaneAdresowe>
    </InformacjeOWpisie>
    <InformacjeOWpisie>
      <DaneAdresowe>
        <AdresGlownegoMiejscaWykonywaniaDzialalnosci>
          <Budynek>8r</Budynek>
          <Lokal>2</Lokal>
          <Wojewodztwo>mazowieckie</Wojewodztwo>
        </AdresGlownegoMiejscaWykonywaniaDzialalnosci>
      </DaneAdresowe>
      </InformacjeOWpisie>
</Dane>
```

Desired output:

```html
<Dane>
  <InformacjeOWpisie>
    <DaneAdresowe>
      <AdresGlownegoMiejscaWykonywaniaDzialalnosci>
        <Budynek>3a</Budynek>
        <Lokal_test/>
        <Wojewodztwo>podlaskie</Wojewodztwo>
      </AdresGlownegoMiejscaWykonywaniaDzialalnosci>
    </DaneAdresowe>
    </InformacjeOWpisie>
    <InformacjeOWpisie>
      <DaneAdresowe>
        <AdresGlownegoMiejscaWykonywaniaDzialalnosci>
          <Budynek>8r</Budynek>
          <Lokal_test>2</Lokal_test>
          <Wojewodztwo>mazowieckie</Wojewodztwo>
        </AdresGlownegoMiejscaWykonywaniaDzialalnosci>
      </DaneAdresowe>
      </InformacjeOWpisie>
</Dane>
```

This question([XSLT: create node if not exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6329843/xslt-create-node-if-it-doesnt-exist) seemed to be the awnser to my problems but when trying to use it does not work.
Not sure why?

```
<xsl:template match="InformacjeOWpisie/DaneAdresowe/AdresGlownegoMiejscaWykonywaniaDzialalnosci/Lokal">
<Lokal_test>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
</Lokal_test>
</xsl:template>
```

**EDIT:**
When I get rid of parent `Lokal_test` dissapears. I use below code to say "bye bye" to parent:

```
<xsl:template match="InformacjeOWpisie/DaneAdresowe/AdresGlownegoMiejscaWykonywaniaDzialalnosci">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You approach was right, but incomplete. You only created the new `Local_test` element.

So try these two templates in combination with the *indentity template*:

```
<!-- Handles the replacement of the 'Lokal' element -->
<xsl:template match="AdresGlownegoMiejscaWykonywaniaDzialalnosci/Lokal">
    <Lokal_test>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
    </Lokal_test>
</xsl:template>

<!-- Creates a new 'Lokal_test' element if no 'Lokal' element exists -->
<xsl:template match="AdresGlownegoMiejscaWykonywaniaDzialalnosci[not(Lokal)]">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()/following-sibling::Wojewodztwo/preceding-sibling::*|@*" />     <!-- Copy nodes before 'Wojewodztwo' -->
        <Lokal_test />
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Wojewodztwo|Wojewodztwo/following-sibling::*|@*" />     <!-- Copy nodes after 'Wojewodztwo' (including) -->
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

The second template puts the `Lokal_test` element *before* the `Wojewodztwo` element and copies the surrounding nodes.

Comment: thank you it does seem to work. However pasted to my code it does not. In other words, it works alone but not with the rest of the code. Plus I cannot seem to put in the right place - it pops up at the end not in the middle where I want to...

Comment: I updated my answer so that the new `Lokal_test` appears before the `Wojewodztwo` tag. What exactly does not work with your full code?

Comment: Alright, I managed to find the problem. When I try to get rid of parent (`AdresGlownegoMiejscaWykonywaniaDzialalnosci`) to newly created `Lokal_test` it disappears after transformation. Parent is not needed in my code but `Lokal_test` is important.

Comment: You can remove/not copy the `AdresGlownegoMiejscaWykonywaniaDzialalnosci` element by removing the `xsl:copy` from the second template. How does your full desired output look like now?

Comment: Tried to isolate the problem but it does not look so easy. Desired output has only: `<Dane>`, `<InformacjeOWpisie>`, `<Budynek>`, `<Lokal_test>` and `<Wojewodztwo>` tags in order and hierarchy.

Comment: This seems to be overwhelmingly different from the desired output you posted above. I guess it's better to post a new and updated question with the right information.

Comment: Well... thought it was a minor thing - had problem with adding `Lokal_test`. Then I guess I will post another question - hope you can take a look at it :)

Answer (score 1):

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
       <xsl:copy>
           <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
       </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="AdresGlownegoMiejscaWykonywaniaDzialalnosci/Budynek">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="exists(following-sibling::Lokal)">
                    <Lokal_test>
                    <xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::Lokal"/>
                    </Lokal_test>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="not(following-sibling::Lokal)">

                    <xsl:element name="Lokal_test"/>
            </xsl:when>
            </xsl:choose>


    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Lokal"/>
```

Comment: It works and it does not at the same time. When pasting in online test tool it works. However Access says: `exists(following-sibling::Lokal)` is not a valid function of XSLT or XPath :(