# XSLT: create node if does not exists and simplify tags tree

Tags: xml, xslt, ms-access-2010, transformation

I know similar questions are already there but none of them seem to work for me. Especially when comes to simplifing XML structure.

So shortly, I have XML file with tag "Lokal" that in most cases does not appear but it should. Not making things easier: I also need to change a name of "Lokal" to let's say "Lokal_test". My goal is modify node name(if exists) or create it and rename (if does not exists).
Data from XML will be imported to MS Access data so they need to match perfectly with table...

Sample XML:

```html
<Dane>
  <InformacjeOWpisie>
    <DaneAdresowe>
      <AdresGlownegoMiejscaWykonywaniaDzialalnosci>
        <Budynek>3a</Budynek>
        <Wojewodztwo>podlaskie</Wojewodztwo>
      </AdresGlownegoMiejscaWykonywaniaDzialalnosci>
    </DaneAdresowe>
    </InformacjeOWpisie>
    <InformacjeOWpisie>
      <DaneAdresowe>
        <AdresGlownegoMiejscaWykonywaniaDzialalnosci>
          <Budynek>8r</Budynek>
          <Lokal>2</Lokal>
          <Wojewodztwo>mazowieckie</Wojewodztwo>
        </AdresGlownegoMiejscaWykonywaniaDzialalnosci>
      </DaneAdresowe>
      </InformacjeOWpisie>
</Dane>
```

Desired output:

```html
<Dane>
  <InformacjeOWpisie>
    <Budynek>3a</Budynek>
    <Lokal_test/>
    <Wojewodztwo>podlaskie</Wojewodztwo>
  </InformacjeOWpisie>
  <InformacjeOWpisie>
    <Budynek>8r</Budynek>
    <Lokal_test>2</Lokal_test>
    <Wojewodztwo>mazowieckie</Wojewodztwo>
  </InformacjeOWpisie>
</Dane>
```

I have already asked for this code in [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50456578/xslt-create-node-if-does-not-exists) question.

Code below worked:

```
<!-- Handles the replacement of the 'Lokal' element -->
<xsl:template match="AdresGlownegoMiejscaWykonywaniaDzialalnosci/Lokal">
    <Lokal_test>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
    </Lokal_test>
</xsl:template>

<!-- Creates a new 'Lokal_test' element if no 'Lokal' element exists -->
<xsl:template match="AdresGlownegoMiejscaWykonywaniaDzialalnosci[not(Lokal)]">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()/following-sibling::Wojewodztwo/preceding-sibling::*|@*" />
<!-- Copy nodes before 'Wojewodztwo' -->
        <Lokal_test />
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Wojewodztwo|Wojewodztwo/following-sibling::*|@*" />
<!-- Copy nodes after 'Wojewodztwo' (including) -->
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

...but applying code to remove `AdresGlownegoMiejscaWykonywaniaDzialalnosci` removes also `Lokal_test` tag.

```
<xsl:template match="InformacjeOWpisie/DaneAdresowe/AdresGlownegoMiejscaWykonywaniaDzialalnosci">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
</xsl:template>
```

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove the unwanted elements by matching them in a template and then only use `<apply-templates>` to process further the descending nodes.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />           <!-- compact output -->

  <!-- identity template -->
  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>  

  <!-- Ignore two elements and only descend further -->
  <xsl:template match="AdresGlownegoMiejscaWykonywaniaDzialalnosci | DaneAdresowe">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
  </xsl:template>  

  <!-- Handles the replacement of the 'Lokal' element -->
  <xsl:template match="AdresGlownegoMiejscaWykonywaniaDzialalnosci/Lokal">
    <Lokal_test>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
    </Lokal_test>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Creates a new 'Lokal_test' element if no 'Lokal' element exists -->
  <xsl:template match="AdresGlownegoMiejscaWykonywaniaDzialalnosci[not(Lokal)]">
      <!-- Here the <xsl:copy> was removed -->
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()/following-sibling::Wojewodztwo/preceding-sibling::*|@*" />
        <!-- Copy nodes before 'Wojewodztwo' -->
        <Lokal_test />
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Wojewodztwo|Wojewodztwo/following-sibling::*|@*" />
        <!-- Copy nodes after 'Wojewodztwo' (including) -->
      <!-- Here the <xsl:copy> was removed -->
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Some changes to apply to the rest of my code and works perfectly. I need to get some more XSLT classes :) Thank you!